# Check if scheduled local agents can run in Notes client

Tags: xpages, lotusscript, xpinc

I there a way in XPiNC (Per can you add that tag) to check if "scheduled local agent" is enabled in a Notes client? Alternatively how to do that in a LotusScript agent. Checking if an agent is active is easy, but that's only one part of the equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Trigger](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESAGENT_CLASS.html) and `IsEnabled` properties of the NotesAgent class:

> ```
> TRIGGER_AFTER_MAIL_DELIVERY (2) means "After new mail has arrived"
> TRIGGER_BEFORE_MAIL_DELIVERY (6) means "Before new mail arrives"
> TRIGGER_DOC_PASTED (3) means "When documents are pasted"
> TRIGGER_DOC_UPDATE (5) means "After documents are created or modified"
> TRIGGER_MANUAL (4) means "Action menu selection" or "Agent list selection"
> TRIGGER_SERVERSTART (8) means "When the Domino server starts"
> TRIGGER_NONE (0) is not used
>
> TRIGGER_SCHEDULED (1) means "More than once a day," "Daily," "Weekly," "Monthly," or "Never"
> ```

**Edit**:
[This forum post suggests](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/869c7412fe5d56b7852569fa007826e3/d35785d5b03f54cb852574f8002eea0b?OpenDocument) checking wether the Notes client is configured to allow running of scheduled agent can be done like this:

```
if (Clng( Session.GetEnvironmentValue( "Preferences", True )) and &H8000000) > 0 then
    msgbox "scheduled agents allowed"
end if
```

Comment: that wasn't my question. isEnabled is also exposed to LotusScript. What I want to check: is the client enabled to run scheduled agents. If an agent is enabled but no the client it won't run either

Comment: I see. Have updated my answer with an example of preferences parsing.