# Reference to the Preferences environment value

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

When answering the question [Check if scheduled local agents can run in Notes client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151443/check-if-scheduled-local-agents-can-run-in-notes-client) I found [a forum post by Javed Khan](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/869c7412fe5d56b7852569fa007826e3/d35785d5b03f54cb852574f8002eea0b?OpenDocument) indicating that this can be checked by checking if a bit in the `Preferences` environment value is set.

```
Const LOCAL_AGENTS = &H8000000
Call Session.SetEnvironmentVar("Preferences", Cstr( Clng( Session.GetEnvironmentValue( "Preferences", True )) Or LOCAL_AGENTS ), True )
```

The "Scheduled local agents" settings is apparently the 28:th bit.

My question is: Is there any online documentation for the meaning of the other bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list, taken from http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/46dom.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/e870840587eed796852568f6006facde?OpenDocument

- 0 <0> = Keep workspace in back when maximized (Enabled=1)
- 1 <2> = Scan for unread
- 2 <4> =
- 3 <8> = Large fonts
- 4 <16> =
- 5 <32> = Make Internet URLs (http//:) into hotspots
- 6 <64> =
- 7 <128> = Typewriter fonts only
- 8 <256> = Monochrome display
- 9 <512> = Scandinavian collation
- 10 <1024> =
- 11 <2048> =
- 12 <4096> = Sign sent mail (Enabled(1))
- 13 <8192> = Encrypt sent mail
- 14 <16384> = Metric(1)/Imperial(0) measurements
- 15 <32768> = Numbers last collation
- 16 <65536> = French casing
- 17 <131072> = empty trash folder (prompt during db close=0/always during db close=1/manual=1
- 18 <262144> = Check for new mail every x minutes (Enabled=0)
- 19 <524288> = Enable local background indexing
- 20 <1048576> = Encrypt saved mail
- 21 <2097152> =
- 22 <4194304> =
- 23 <8388608> = Right double-click closes window
- 24 <16777216> = Prompt for location
- 25 <33554432> =
- 26 <67108864> = Mark documents read when opened in the preview pane
- 27 <134217728> = Enable local scheduled agents
- 28 <268435456> = Save sent mail (Always prompt=10/Don't keep a copy=00/Always keep a  copy=01)
- 29 <536870912> =
- 30 <1073741824> = New mail notification (None=10/Audible=00/Visible=01)
- 31 <2147483648> =